# Cannot find option to edit people in Nexus 4

Tags: nexus-4, people-app, pac-rom

My device is Nexus 4 with custom PACman ROM installed. It got into a bootloop while taking a pic,So I swiped the dalvik cache and system files using TWRP.
It booted up finely But since then i couldnt find the overflow button in people. Anybody have any idea...?

Comment: I'd say this is a pac specific issue.  Where did you get the ROM?

Comment: xda developers pac_mako_nighty_20130921

Comment: Then I'd suggest asking on the thread where you got the ROM.  It's either a known bug or someone with specific knowledge about the ROM will be able to help you.